# jquery: loading html page inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading an html page inside a div using:

```
$("#page1").html('<object data="http://stackoverflow.com/">');
```

the problem is that the loaded page is very small in display: the div is `500*500px` but the page inside of it is only `100*100px`, no matter what i do.

please help me solve this
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add height width while creating object:

```
$("#page1").html('<object width="100%" height="100%" data="http://stackoverflow.com/">');
```

Comment: @DharaParmar You changed `500` to `100%` and posted new answer.

Comment: @Mohammad i have posted answer with my own without taking reference from yours...

Comment: @DharaParmar I say your answer is like my answer but you posted it.

Comment: @Mohammad.. no..both are different answers...you have use html and i have used jquery only

Answer (score 1):

Use `width` and `height` attribute in `object` tag.

```
<object data="http://stackoverflow.com/" width="500" height="500">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Jquery load** function. It will help you.
Here is the example:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Include</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="include"></div>
            <a id="link" href="#">Click Test Link</a>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $("#link").click(function(){
                    $("#include").load("include/test.html"); 
                });
            </script> 
        </body>
    </html>
```